# Add header information to my Web Service Reference request

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I want to add header information to my Web Service, which I created with basic wizard in Visual Studio 2012.

I simply clicked "Add Service Reference", gave my link and VS created the code itself. Which class do I have to use to pass the header information of my request? Do I have to override the code that VS created automatically?

One more note: If you know another way to add a header to a web service, I would like to use it too. I don't have to use automaticaly created codes. (Although it's handy to use them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net Framework creates and patches the header on its own in the background, so what I should be doing is to add the username-password header values on web.config, instead of binding it to the post itself.

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://ServiceAdd/FService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="FServiceSoapBinding" contract="MyReference.MService_"
     name="FServicePort" >
        <headers>
            <Account>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>password</password>
            </Account>
        </headers>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```